# How can I run Blazor WebAsm project without having launchsettings.json?

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I created a solution with default/classic Blazor webasm projects -- server, client, shared. Within the Server project there is directory "Properties" with "launchsettings.json".

My personal preference would be to get rid of this file (I try to keep really needed stuff), but when I run the Server project (with JetBrains Rider) relying on launchsettings.json both Blazor page is loaded and I get hit API endpoints.

When I "just" run the Server project no relying on "launchsettings.json" I can access API ednpoints, but when I go to main page Blazor page does not load.

I don't see anything special in "launchsettings.json" related to Blazor, maybe it is some Rider thing, but anyway, how can I run simply Server project and remove this file for good?